# How to test button click on jest/enzyme without props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test is the button clicked and some actions happens but I fail the test and receive 0 number of calls when clicked. Im not passing onclick function from props.
I'm using materialUi Button

```
const LoginFunction = () => {

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('some action here')
  };

  return (
    <Button
        data-test="btn"
        className='btn'
        onClick={() => {
            handleClick();
        }}
    >
       Some text
    </Button>
 )};
```

I wrote test like this

```
describe('Test Login component', () => {

  it('should trigger click event', () => {
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<LoginFunction />);

    wrapper.simulate('click');
    expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
   }); 
 });
```

Tried this way too

```
 describe('Test Login component', () => {

  it('should trigger click event', () => {
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<LoginFunction />);

    wrapper.find('.btn').simulate('click');
    expect(mockCallBack.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
   }); 
 });
```

Comment: `mockCallBack` is not be called.  That's why the assertion fails. You may want to pass the callback as a prop to the `LoginFunction` component and call it

Comment: BUt I'm not calling handleClick function from props, if I write like this - const wrapper = shallow(<LoginFunction  handleClick={mockCallBack}/>); thats will not work. I'm looking for solution when I won't need to pass as an props

Answer (score 0):

```
**Also in the main component you can directly call the handler in onclick like this** 

     <Button
            data-test="btn"
            className='btn'
            onClick={handleClick}
        >
           Some text
        </Button>

describe('Test Login component', () => {

  it('should trigger click event', () => {
  const wrapper=mount( <LoginFunction />);
    const result=wrapper.find('button').simulate('click')
   expect(result).toBe('some action here')
 });
```

Comment: I should separate files, the same problem may be in other tests too, is ther any way to do with different files?

Comment: Sorry could you be more specific. Please post that chunk of code for which you want to test

Comment: I posted my whole component, which is a simple component that include button, I should write test for button, when button was triggered. And the main problem is that I dont want to write function outside and pass with props, I want to write button click function inside the component.